# Windows 10 SSD maintenance/defragmentation/compression query

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, compression, defragment, samsung-ssd

I have a 1TB Samsung EVO SSD as my system drive (Windows 10). I let it get almost full and paid the price - performance writing new files dropped off by a factor of something like a thousand.

I stopped what I was doing (reading/writing 20 million or so small files for a job that would benefit from high disk speed) and removed all those files. Free space is now at 354 out of 874GB and I should be able to get some more back with some work. The SSD is no longer my go-to utility performance drive for bulk operations.

My questions are:

1. Is there something I should do to defragment the drive, or will Windows and/or the driver do this for me?
2. Should I enable compression on the SSD? My CPU is plenty capable of handling the overhead, but after witnessing the enormous performance penalty of filling up the drive, I'm now wondering about other effects particular to SSDs relating to Windows drive compression.

Update...
I freed up 408 out of 874 GB on the drive, and it still showed a dramatic performance penalty - a program that runs in 1.1 seconds on the HDD runs in 63 seconds on the SSD. This is appending a few lines to a file two thousand times, but closing the file each time. I got suspicious of this and tried disabling Bit Defender antivirus. Suddenly the program runs in 1.1 seconds on the SSD as well. So Bitdefender is forcing the entire file to be read (and not from cache) two thousand times. On the HDD it is probably forcing the re-read as well, but it appears to be using cache. I guess I don't need Bit Defender.

I checked the system settings and the SSD drive was set to 'Weekly Optimisation'. I ran an optimisation, and all that ran was 'Trim'. Apparently Windows 10 doesn't normally defragment SSDs, they don't require it and just incur extra wear. It just runs the trim operation which garbage collects unused blocks.

So I can rest easy, no further action required to get my SSD going at 'full speed'.

Comment: Even with 10% OP in Magician? 93GB of OP _(the default)_ should be sufficient to not have that occur, however that's on the drive's firmware side - on the OS side, partitions should always have a minimum 10% free ,_(an OS' drive performance will dramatically slow if the partition no longer has an amount of free space necessary for OS and program functionality)_

Comment: Yup turns out the massive slow down was just antivirus related. I hate AV.

Comment: With Windows ≥10, third party antivirus isn't needed, as Defender in ≥10 is on par with top rated third party antivirus solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SSD Defragmentation is generally a [not advisable](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/defrag-an-ssd.html). There was a bug in Windows that caused [excessive automatic defragmentation](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-fixes-windows-10-bug-causing-excessive-ssd-defragging/), "affecting an  SSD drives' [sic] longevity". Since there are a finite number of write cycles for each byte, moving files significantly shortened the SSD lifetime.
2. The best way to find out if compression speeds or slows I/O throughput is to test it on a particular machine, because of variables such as CPU speed, SSD read speed, etc. Copy one large folder, and compress one, rather than the whole SSD. To compress a folder, right-click the folder, select *Properties*, click the *Advanced* button, and set *Compress...* . Perform some operations such as copying a folder, or search the contents with an un-indexed tool, such as Mythiscsoft's [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), and see which works better on your setup.